# pyodbc not committing changes to db2 database

Tags: python, python-3.x, db2, pyodbc

I am trying to update my db2 database using pyodbc in python. The sql statement runs normally without errors on the database directly. when I run the code below, I get no errors and the code executes successfully but when I query the database, the changes did not save.

```
try:
    conn2 = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};SYSTEM="+ Config_Main.iseriesServer +";DATABASE="+ Config_Main.iseriesDB +";UID="+ Config_Main.iseriesUser +";PWD=" + Config_Main.iseriesPass)
    db2 = conn2.cursor()

    for row in encludeData:
        count = len(str(row[2]))
        srvid = row[2]
        if count < 10:
            sql3 = "UPDATE SVCEN2DEV.SRVMAST SET svbrch = ? WHERE svtype != '*DCS-' AND svacct = ? AND svcid LIKE '%?' and svbrch = ?"
            db2.execute(sql3, (row[4],row[1],"%" + str(srvid),row[5]))
        else:
            sql3 = "UPDATE SVCEN2DEV.SRVMAST SET svbrch = ? WHERE svtype != '*DCS-' AND svacct = ? AND svcid = ? and svbrch = ?"
            db2.execute(sql3, (row[4],row[1],srvid,row[5]))
        conn2.commit()
except pyodbc.Error as e:
    logging.error(e)
```

I have tried setting `conn2.autocommit = True`. and I have also tried moving the `conn2.commit()` inside of the for loop to commit after each iteration. I also tried a different driver `{IBM i Access ODBC Driver}`

**EDIT:**

Sample of `encludeData`

```
['4567890001','4567890001','1234567890','1234567890','foo','bar']
```

After changing the except statement to grab general errors, the code above now produces this error:

> IntegrityError('23000', '[23000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0803 - Duplicate key value specified. (-803) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Comment: If you have no try:..., except:,   blocks how do you know that the code executed successfully?  Also, from your code sample we cannot know what is `encludedata`, so how do you know that the for loop runs any code?

Comment: I can see why first `UPDATE` does not work and interestingly does not raise a syntax error (maybe will a warning exception) as you are attempting to concatenate a wildcard with placeholder symbol, `?`. Be sure types match between Python variables  and db2 columns.

Comment: @mao I have updated my code.

Comment: @Parfait I have ensured the types match but it doesn't work on either SQL. I made test data to only hit the second SQL and still no luck.

Comment: Maybe update conditions return zero rows. Try running the `SELECT` version: `SELECT svbrch FROM SVCEN2DEV.SRVMAST WHERE svtype != '*DCS-' AND svacct = ? AND svcid = ? and svbrch = ?` Do remember Python structures are zero based index, where `row[0]` means the first item. And change except to the general: `except Exception as e` and put the `conn2.close()` in the `finally` block.

Comment: @Parfait I believe you answered my original issue. I have spotted the error hidden after updating my code as you instructed. the error is `IntegrityError('23000', '[23000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0803 - Duplicate key value specified. (-803) (SQLExecDirectW)')`

Comment: @Pintang - Comments are good for asking/answering questions re: clarification of the problem, but comments themselves are considered "disposable" so significant new pieces of information should either **(1)** be added to the question via an [edit] (if the question is still unresolved), **(2)** be posted as an answer (if that answer might be helpful to others in the future), or **(3)** cause the question to be deleted (if the source of the problem was just a silly mistake).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As OP found out, the application layer language, Python, may not raise specific database exceptions such as duplicate index or foreign key issues and hence will silently fail or will be logged on server side. Usually errors that affect actual SQL queries to run like incorrect identifiers and syntax errors will raise an error on client side.

Therefore, as best practice in programming it is necessary to use exception handling like Python's `try/except/finally` or the equivalent in other general purpose languages that interface with any external API like database connections in order to catch and properly handle runtime issues.

Below will print *any* exception on statements raised in the `try` block including connection and query execution. And regardless of success or fail will run the `finally` statements.

```
try:
    conn2 = pyodbc.connect(...)
    db2 = conn2.cursor()

    sql = "..."
    db2.execute(sql, params)
    conn2.commit()

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    db2.close()
    conn2.close()
```